# Assigning a custom URL mapping to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, grails

I've created a URL custom controller for one of my pages:

```
class SummaryController {
    def show(String param1, String params2) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and a corresponding URL mapping for it.

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        ...
        name special:"/dir1/subdir/$param1/$param2/summary"{
            controller="summary"
            action="show"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly when I type the address in a browser's address bar. Now what I want is to save that URL into a javascript variable. But there is an error generated when creating URL String:

```
<script>
    var URL =
        "${ g.createLink(mapping: "special", params: "[param1: '...', param2: '...']") }"
</script>
```

> **Message:** Unable to create URL for mapping `[/dir1/subdir/(*)/(*)]` and parameters `[{controller=summary, action=show}]`. Parameter `[param1]` is required, but was not specified!

Although the following code, when written in `<body>`, works:

```
<body>
    ....
    <li>
        <g:link mapping="special" params="[param1: '...', params2: '...']" />
            Link
        </g:link>
    </li>
    ..
</body>
```

What with `g:link` that is not with `g.createLink()`? Is there a way assign the custom URL value to a JavaScript variable? This is Grails 2.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `String` parameter, instead of `Map`. Remember that inside a `${}` should be valid Groovy code, same as you're using in groovy classes.

Try this:

```
<script>
    var URL =
        "${ g.createLink(mapping: 'special', params: [param1: '...', param2: '...']) }";
</script>
```

which is similar to:

```
def g = ...
g.createLink(
    mapping: 'special', 
    params: [
       param1: '...', 
       param2: '...'
    ]
)
// your code was passing a string instead:
g.createLink(
    mapping: 'special', 
    params: "[param1: '...', param2: '...']"
)
```